# Regex match single word

Tags: java, regex

Waht is the java regex to match only "pkgName" from string:

```
"name=pkgname -path=some.apk -minutes=120"
```

I have tried:

```
public static final Pattern PKG_NAME_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(name=)(\\b.+\\b)\\s");
```

buit group 2 of Match gives me:  "pkgname -path=some.apk -minutes=120"

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the java regex to match **only** "pkgName" from string:

You can use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=name=)\S+
```

- `(?<=name=)` is positive look-behind to assert that previous position has `name=`
- `\S+` will match 1 or more non-space characters

Using Java:

```
public static final Pattern PKG_NAME_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?<=name=)\\S+");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/3)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    String s = "name=pkgname -path=some.apk -minutes=120";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name=(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Repace the dot by word character:

```
"(name=)(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s"
```

and the word boundaries are not usfull here:

```
"(name=)(\\w+)\\s"
```